# Abaqus: empty job monitor

Tags: abaqus

I just installed Abaqus and run first job. When I open job monitor I see some data in "Message File" and "Data File" sections, but Errors, Warnings (despite there are warnings and errors during the calculation) and table with Steps and Increment are empty.

Do you have any idea what I can do to see the job progress in data monitor?

Comment: I just realized that in .log file there is a warning _WARNING: Interactive messaging has been requested for this analysis run, but initialization of the messaging system has failed.  Therefore no messages will be sent to Abaqus/CAE for this phase of the analysis._ Also, in .sta file there is all information about steps and increments, which are usually printed in job monitor.

Answer (score 0):

> To fix this error, add the following line to the `custom_v6.env` file in the Simulia installation folder:
>
> ```
> cae_local_host="localhost"
> ```

REF: https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/structural-mechanics/232704-abaqus-socket-error-errno-10060-a.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: ... please understand that linked content is not considered part of an answer on StackOverflow. So even if the explanation is linked, a summary should be added directly here.